# Elements on Higher Z-Index Being Influenced by Transparent Div on Lower Z-Index

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty simple setup for a web page, consisting of a grid of divs, headers, and i elements:

[image: Before background div]

All I want to do is add a div with a background color and a header behind this grid, with the elements of the grid appear on top of the new background div.

However, when I try to do this, I get this:

[image: After new div]

As you can see, the transparent color of the background div is overlapping the buttons, only in the grid.

I've made sure to adjust the z-index of all elements (the background div, the grid and all of it's elements) so that they do have higher z-index value than the background div.

Here is my HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```
<html>
...
<body>
    <div id="sfa3features"><h1>New SFA3 Features!</h1></div>
    ...
    <div class="wrapper-how-to" id="grid-menu3">

        <div class="row-top"></div>
        <h2 class="row-top label-cell">Setting</h2>
        <div class="row-top"></div>
        <div class="row-top"></div>
        <div class="row-top"></div>
        <div class="row-top"></div>

        <i class="image-cell fa fa-info-circle fa-2x"></i>
        <h3 class="label-cell">Combo Items</h3>

        <div id="combo_items_finding"  class="box-how-to enabled"><h3>Finding</h3>   <span class="popup popup-how-to" id="popup_combo_items_finding" > </div>
        <div id="combo_items_updating" class="box-how-to impossible"><h3>Updating</h3>  <span class="popup popup-how-to" id="popup_combo_items_updating" ></div>
        <div id="combo_items_entering" class="box-how-to enabled"><h3>Entering</h3>  <span class="popup popup-how-to" id="popup_combo_items_entering" ></div>
        <div id="combo_items_linking"  class="box-how-to impossible"><h3>Linking</h3><span class="popup popup-how-to" id="popup_combo_items_linking"  ></div>

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper-how-to" id="grid-menu4">

        <div class="row-top"></div>
        <h2 class="row-top label-cell">Pickbox</h2>
        <div class="row-top"></div>
        <div class="row-top"></div>
        <div class="row-top"></div>
        <div class="row-top"></div>

        <i class="image-cell fa fa-folder-o fa-2x"></i>
        <h3 class="label-cell">Pickbox</h3>

        <div id="pickbox_finding"  class="box-how-to enabled"><h3>Finding</h3>   <span class="popup popup-how-to" id="popup_pickbox_finding" > </div>
        <div id="pickbox_updating" class="box-how-to enabled"><h3>Updating</h3>  <span class="popup popup-how-to" id="popup_pickbox_updating" ></div>
        <div id="pickbox_entering" class="box-how-to enabled"><h3>Entering</h3>  <span class="popup popup-how-to" id="popup_pickbox_entering" ></div>
        <div id="pickbox_linking"  class="box-how-to impossible"><h3>Linking</h3><span class="popup popup-how-to" id="popup_pickbox_linking"  ></div>

    </div>

...
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper-how-to {

    display: grid;

    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 5% 22% 16% 16% 16% 16%;

    background-color: transparent;
    color: #444;
    margin: 2.5% auto !important;
}

.wrapper-how-to h2,
.wrapper-how-to h3,
.wrapper-how-to div,
.wrapper-how-to i
{
    z-index:2;
}


#sfa3features{
    /*Should be the same as coverup5, but back layer*/

    display: flex;

    position: absolute;
    width: 105%;
    left:-4%;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;

    background-color: rgba(255, 219, 89,0.8);
    border-color: rgb(252, 204, 30);
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-width: 5px;

    z-index: -1;

    height: 400px;
    top:1485px;
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You should run your code thru a html validator, you have a bunch of unclosed span tags

Answer (score 0):

I was getting confused. The div elements have a transparent color. Of course they will use the background div's color as well.

Switching CSS to opaque colors should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, it really was because I was using an transparent color.